# django mongodbforms exception when rendering embedded formset management_form

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I'm using mongodbforms to connect to MongoDB in my django project. I want to use embedded formset to populate a list of embedded fields. Everything works just fine when I only try to render one form in a formset. However when I set `extra=3` and try to render `management_form` for an embedded formset I get an exception.
Here is my `model.py`:

```
from mongoengine import *
from MongoNotes.settings import DBNAME

connect(DBNAME)

class CollectionField(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)

class Collection(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    collection_fields = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(CollectionField))
```

here is my form and a formset (please note `extra=3` - this is causing an execption:

```
# coding=utf-8
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from mongodbforms import embeddedformset_factory, EmbeddedDocumentForm
from MongoNotes.apps.Notes.models import CollectionField, Collection

class FieldForm(EmbeddedDocumentForm):
    class Meta:
        document = CollectionField
        embedded_field_name = 'collection_fields'

        fields = ['name',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'collection_field_form'
        self.helper.form_tag = False

FieldFormSet = embeddedformset_factory(CollectionField, Collection, form=FieldForm, extra=3)
```

this is a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Add collection</h1>
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            {{ field_formset.management_form }}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

for completeness here is my view:

```
# coding=utf-8
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from MongoNotes.apps.Notes.forms import FieldFormSet
from models import Collection

class AddCollectionView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'add_collection.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddCollectionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['field_formset'] = FieldFormSet(prefix='field', parent_document=Collection())
        return context
```

running this gives me an exception:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'MongoNotes.apps.Notes',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Template error:
In template C:\projects\mongodbforms_error\MongoNotes\apps\Notes\templates\add_collection.html, error at line 8
   list index out of range
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html>
   3 :     <head>
   4 :     </head>
   5 :     <body>
   6 :         <h1>Add collection</h1>
   7 :         <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
   8 :              {{ field_formset.management_form }} 
   9 :         </form>
   10 :     </body>
   11 : </html>

Traceback:
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
  88.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  585.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  735.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  765.                     current = current[bit]
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in __getitem__
  69.         return self.forms[index]
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __get__
  49.         res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in forms
  133.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in xrange(self.total_form_count())]
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\mongodbforms\documents.py" in _construct_form
  930.         form = super(EmbeddedDocumentFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **defaults)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in _construct_form
  157.         form = self.form(**defaults)
File "C:\projects\mongodbforms_error\MongoNotes\apps\Notes\forms.py" in __init__
  15.         super(FieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\mongodbforms\documents.py" in __init__
  548.                 instance = getattr(parent_document, self._meta.embedded_field)[position]
File "C:\(...)\mongodbforms_error\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  96.         value = super(BaseList, self).__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: IndexError at /
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

I've tried to debug this myself, but I'm not skilled enough in Python to find out what is a source of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Django MongoDBForms is no longer maintained by its original creator, and has now diverged into a mess of forks. I made a few small fixes on the embedded document formset code on one of them. I'm not sure if they would have fixed your problem, but something that may be useful is to use one of the more recently updated forks of the project rather than the original.

I can't recommend one to solve your problem specifically but I notice that this fork has taken the changes I made and advanced further on them. https://github.com/baffolobill/django-mongodbforms